# Packaging a Python program that needs to a C compiler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, packaging, python-packaging

I'm creating and packaging a Python (2.7) program to create a Lambda Function on Amazaon WS. The program I have is dependent on the [PySha3 package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3), which is essentially a Python wrapper around the optimized Sha3 C package. Pysha3 imports a C file; the source code of these two files can be seen in [this Github Repository](https://github.com/tiran/pysha3).

In order to import a package into the Lambda platform, the whole file and all dependencies must be zipped and uploaded. When I do this and attempt to test the package after the upload I get an error that the Sha3 classes being imported from the C file included in PySha3's package cannot be found. As I result of my own research and troubleshooting I have decided to install a Pysha3 wheel in the root of my program's directory, which I do believe is the right move. However, when I do this I get the error below:

[image]

I'm really hoping that if I can get the wheel to install correctly by installing a C compiler and can somehow package the C compiler along with my program, that the Lambda will then work. I found [this compiler for Python](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and I'm hoping that installing it will fix my error locally, and maybe including it in the zip file will fix the error on Lambda AWS.

So, my question is, does my thought process seem valid? As well, any tips/guidance on how to include the compiler in a zipped file so that it will actually be utilized? I'm very new to all of this, so anything will help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to package a binary for Lambda, you need to build any native code in the correct environment.  It appears that you are trying to build on a Windows machine -- even if your build worked, the resulting binary would not be suitable for the Lambda execution environment.

The current supported environment is documented in the [Lambda Execution Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#main-col-body) guide, which states also:

> If you are using any native binaries in your code, make sure they are compiled in this environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for this info - I'll try to work through it from here!

Comment: I took the compiled binary from the package site (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3), unzipped it with 7z on my Windows PC and then added the compiled binaries to my project directory. 
Uploading the zipped project directory with the compiled Linux binary worked! I used pysha3-1.0.2-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl